# YARN-Cgroups : Failed to initialize container executor in non-secure cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, cgroups

I am trying to use cgroups with YARN 2.6.0 in non-secure mode. It works
fine if I use DefaultContainerExecutor. But, I get error when I try to use LinuxContainerExecutor.

Now, when I execute --> $ yarn nodemanager, it fails

```
ExitCodeException exitCode=24: File /home/hduser2/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop must be owned by root, but is owned by 1001

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.init(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:181)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:509)
15/08/08 23:07:39 INFO nodemanager.ContainerExecutor: 
15/08/08 23:07:39 INFO service.AbstractService: Service NodeManager failed in state INITED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to initialize container executor
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to initialize container executor
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:509)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Linux container executor not configured properly (error=24)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.init(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:209)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=24: File /home/hduser2/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop must be owned by root, but is owned by 1001

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.init(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:181)
    ... 4 more
15/08/08 23:07:39 WARN service.AbstractService: When stopping the service NodeManager : java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.stopRecoveryStore(NodeManager.java:161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceStop(NodeManager.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.stop(AbstractService.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stop(ServiceOperations.java:52)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.ServiceOperations.stopQuietly(ServiceOperations.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:509)
15/08/08 23:07:39 FATAL nodemanager.NodeManager: Error starting NodeManager
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Failed to initialize container executor
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.initAndStartNodeManager(NodeManager.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:509)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Linux container executor not configured properly (error=24)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.init(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeManager.serviceInit(NodeManager.java:209)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=24: File /home/hduser2/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop must be owned by root, but is owned by 1001

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.init(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:181)
    ... 4 more
15/08/08 23:07:39 INFO nodemanager.NodeManager: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

Site specific YARN configuration properties are :

```
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.container-executor.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor</value> 
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.resources-handler.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.util.CgroupsLCEResourcesHandler</value> 
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.cgroups.hierarchy</name>
        <value>/hadoop-yarn</value> 
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.cgroups.mount</name>
        <value>true</value> 
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.cgroups.mount-path</name>
        <value>/cgroup</value> 
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.group</name>
        <value>hadoop</value> 
</property>
<property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.percentage-physical-cpu-limit</name>
        <value>95</value>
</property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.cgroups.strict-resource-usage</name>
            <value>true</value>
    </property>
```

and container-executor.cfg is:

```
yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.group=hadoop
min.user.id=1000
```

It would be great if someone can please help me figure out what’s wrong with my setup.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue can be explained in the stack-trace here:

`Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=24: File /home/hduser2/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop must be owned by root, but is owned by 1001`

The entire path containing container-executor.cfg must be owned and writable only by root.

Likely the problem can be solved by 

`chown root:root /home/hduser2/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop`

Though you may need to continue up the path changing ownership.

Answer (score -1):

Adding the below property in all the NM will solve your issue

```
yarn.nodemanager.linux-container-executor.nonsecure-mode.limit-users = false
```